# Multi-page document with horizontal tables

Tags: tables, landscape

I am composing a multi-page document that contains only tables. Pages are A4 (lettersize) in "landscape"(!) orientation, each page has only one table.
I am using `landscape`  environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english} 
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|}
some table
\end{tabular}
\newpage
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|}
some table
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The code works, however, I am not exactly sure that my implementation is the best one.
Questions:

1. should I make a separate landscape environment for each page?
2. the page numbers appear on left margin of landscape pages (which is technically the bottom of the page). Is it possible to move them?

**Edit:** I forgot to add `pdfscape` package to minimal example.

Comment: Just add landscape to your document class options.

Comment: your example produces `! LaTeX Error: Environment landscape undefined.` so we can not run it but as Leandriis said use the landscape option (and delete the undefined landscape environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape]{report}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|}
some table
\end{tabular}

\newpage
\begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|}
some table
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```